# How to add and update hash table values to SharePoint custom list?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

I was having SharePoint custom list.List name list1.

For storing Column names I was using another list list2

In product list I want to add hashtable values.Please someone help for this.

Here is my code :

```
enter code here  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Hashtable htValues = new Hashtable();
                            string ITEMNMBR = dr["ITEMNMBR"].ToString();
                            string ItemDesc = dr["Item Desc"].ToString();
                            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
                            //<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ITEMNMBR'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ITEMNMBR + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                            oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ITEMNMBR' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ITEMNMBR + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                            SPListItemCollection oItemColl = olist.GetItems(oQuery);
                            SPListItem oItems = null;
                            if (oItemColl.Count > 0)
                            {
                                oItems = oItemColl[0];
                            }




                            if (oItems != null)
                            {

                                string strContractID = oItems.ID.ToString();
                                foreach (SPListItem items in sqlfields)
                                {
                                    string Sqlcolumns = items["SqlFields"].ToString();
                                    string econtractscolumns = items["eContractsFields"].ToString();
                                    if (dt.Columns.Contains(Sqlcolumns))
                                    {
                                        if (!htValues.Contains(econtractscolumns))
                                            htValues.Add(econtractscolumns, dr[Sqlcolumns]);
                                    }
                                    ///Update Contracts list witH SQL data's

                                }
                       //here how we can pass the htvalues to oitems.update
                                oItems.Update()
                                     }
                            else
                            {
                                Hashtable htnewValues = new Hashtable();
                                foreach (SPListItem items in sqlfields)
                                {
                                    string Productcolumns = items["SqlFields"].ToString();
                                    string econtractscolumns = items["eContractsFields"].ToString();
                                    if (dt.Columns.Contains(Productcolumns))
                                    {
                                        if (!htnewValues.Contains(econtractscolumns))
                                            htnewValues.Add(econtractscolumns, dr[Productcolumns]);
                                    }
                                }
                                SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
                       //here how can i pass the htnewvalues to itemtoadd
                                itemToAdd.Update();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code to **insert & update item** using `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of `HashTable`.

Kindly check it.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> htValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string ITEMNMBR = dr["ITEMNMBR"].ToString();
    string ItemDesc = dr["Item Desc"].ToString();
    SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
    //<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ITEMNMBR'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ITEMNMBR + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

    oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ITEMNMBR' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ITEMNMBR + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
    SPListItemCollection oItemColl = olist.GetItems(oQuery);
    SPListItem oItems = null;
    if (oItemColl.Count > 0)
    {
        oItems = oItemColl[0];
    }




    if (oItems != null)
    {

        string strContractID = oItems.ID.ToString();
        foreach (SPListItem items in sqlfields)
        {
            string Sqlcolumns = items["SqlFields"].ToString();
            string econtractscolumns = items["eContractsFields"].ToString();
            if (dt.Columns.Contains(Sqlcolumns))
            {
                if (!htValues.Contains(econtractscolumns))
                    htValues.Add(econtractscolumns, Sqlcolumns);
            }
            ///Update Contracts list witH SQL data's

        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in sourceList) {
           oItems.id = item.key;
           //you need to compare these values coming from dictionary to each item.
           oItems["item1"] = item.Value;
        }

        //here how we can pass the htvalues to oitems.update
        oItems.Update()

             }
    else
    {
        static Dictionary<string, string> htnewValuesValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (SPListItem items in sqlfields)
        {
            string Productcolumns = items["SqlFields"].ToString();
            string econtractscolumns = items["eContractsFields"].ToString();
            if (dt.Columns.Contains(Productcolumns))
            {
                if (!htnewValues.Contains(econtractscolumns))
                    htnewValues.Add(econtractscolumns, Productcolumns);
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in sourceList) {
        SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
        itemToAdd.id = item.key;
           //you need to compare these values coming from dictionary to each item.
           itemToAdd["item1"] = item.Value;
        itemToAdd.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any question.